# valgrind giving error but unable to find location

Tags: c, memory-leaks, makefile, valgrind, dlopen

I have started using `valgrind` just one day ago as suggested by someone on SO itself .Its an amazing tool but today i got an issue with it.It gives the following error : `definitely lost bytes` but unable to tell the location of error.

Here is the output of `valgrind` :

```
 udit@udit-Dabba ~ $  valgrind --leak-check=full  sendip -v -p ipv6 
 -f file.txt -6s ::1 -p ah -as 0x20 -aq 0x40 -ak "yugal" -am xorauth.so
 -p udp -us 21 -  ud 21 ::2 

 ==12885== Memcheck, a memory error detector
 ==12885== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
 ==12885== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
 ==12885== Command: sendip -v -p ipv6 -f file.txt -6s ::1 -p ah 
 -as 0x20 -aq 0x40 -ak "yugal" -am xorauth.so -p udp -us 21 -ud 21 ::2
 ==12885== 
 Added 19 options
 Initializing module ipv6
 Initializing module ah
 Initializing module udp
 Finalizing module udp
 Finalizing module ah
 Finalizing module ipv6
 Final packet data:
 60 00 00 00   `...
 00 38 33 20   .83 
 /*rest packet data*/
 73 62 68 64   sbhd
 66 67 68 79   fghy
 68 61 62 63   habc
Freeing module ipv6
Freeing module ah
Freeing module udp
==12885== 
==12885== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12885==     in use at exit: 875 bytes in 7 blocks
==12885==   total heap usage: 115 allocs, 108 frees, 9,587 bytes allocated
==12885== 
==12885== 52 (16 direct, 36 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely 
lost in loss record 5 of 7
==12885==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==12885==    by 0x4032ADA: ???
==12885==    by 0x40320EF: ???
==12885==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
==12885== 
==12885== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12885==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==12885==    indirectly lost: 36 bytes in 1 blocks
==12885==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12885==    still reachable: 823 bytes in 5 blocks
==12885==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12885== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==12885== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==12885== 
==12885== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12885== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 35 from 11)
```

Where exactly is the error ????

**Actually i am linking the `xorauth.so` file in the command here and it fills some**
  **authentication data in an optional field but it is unable to do so.**

**No optional authentication data apppearing at its position after running the command and

  `valgrind` also says `definitely lost bytes` but it does not tell where is the problem ?**
Also I tried with this variation of `valgrind` :

```
  udit@udit-Dabba ~ $  valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes 
  sendip -v -p ipv6 -f file.txt -6s ::1 -p ah -as 0x20 -aq 0x40 
  -ak "yugal" -am xorauth.so -p udp -us 21 -ud 21 ::2 

  ==12893== Memcheck, a memory error detector
  ==12893== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
  ==12893== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
  ==12893== Command: sendip -v -p ipv6 -f file.txt -6s ::1 -p ah -as 0x20
 -aq 0x40 -ak yugal -am xorauth.so -p udp -us 21 -ud 21 ::2
 ==12893== 
 Added 19 options
 Initializing module ipv6
 Initializing module ah
 Initializing module udp
 Finalizing module udp
 Finalizing module ah
 Finalizing module ipv6
 Final packet data:
 60 00 00 00   `...
 00 38 33 20   .83 
 /*rest packet data*/
 66 67 68 79   fghy
 68 61 62 63   habc

 Freeing module ipv6
 Freeing module ah
 Freeing module udp
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==12893==     in use at exit: 875 bytes in 7 blocks
 ==12893==   total heap usage: 115 allocs, 108 frees, 9,587 bytes allocated
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==12893==    by 0x400CDE8: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:510)
 ==12893==    by 0x40125BA: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:263)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012145: _dl_open (dl-open.c:555)
 ==12893==    by 0x40408BA: dlopen_doit (dlopenold.c:55)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x40402CB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 ==12893==    by 0x4040936: dlopen@GLIBC_2.0 (dlopenold.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032BB3: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x40320EF: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==12893==    by 0x4004E3E: local_strdup (dl-load.c:162)
 ==12893==    by 0x4007DD8: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2183)
 ==12893==    by 0x401255A: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:226)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012145: _dl_open (dl-open.c:555)
 ==12893==    by 0x40408BA: dlopen_doit (dlopenold.c:55)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x40402CB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 ==12893==    by 0x4040936: dlopen@GLIBC_2.0 (dlopenold.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032BB3: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x40320EF: ???

 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==12893==    by 0x400AA70: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:161)
 ==12893==    by 0x4005F8F: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:957)
 ==12893==    by 0x4007E92: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2250)
 ==12893==    by 0x401255A: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:226)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012145: _dl_open (dl-open.c:555)
 ==12893==    by 0x40408BA: dlopen_doit (dlopenold.c:55)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x40402CB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 ==12893==    by 0x4040936: dlopen@GLIBC_2.0 (dlopenold.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032BB3: ???
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 36 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 4 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032AF3: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x40320EF: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 52 (16 direct, 36 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely
 lost in loss record 5 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032ADA: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x40320EF: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x4025355: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)   
 ==12893==    by 0x400FC84: _dl_check_map_versions (dl-version.c:300)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012810: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:269)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012145: _dl_open (dl-open.c:555)
 ==12893==    by 0x40408BA: dlopen_doit (dlopenold.c:55)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x40402CB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)

 ==12893==    by 0x4040936: dlopen@GLIBC_2.0 (dlopenold.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032BB3: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x40320EF: ???
 ==12893==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== 649 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
 ==12893==    at 0x4025355: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
 ==12893==    by 0x400A842: _dl_new_object (dl-object.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4005F8F: _dl_map_object_from_fd (dl-load.c:957)
 ==12893==    by 0x4007E92: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2250)
 ==12893==    by 0x401255A: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:226)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x4012145: _dl_open (dl-open.c:555)
 ==12893==    by 0x40408BA: dlopen_doit (dlopenold.c:55)
 ==12893==    by 0x400E4D5: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 ==12893==    by 0x40402CB: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 ==12893==    by 0x4040936: dlopen@GLIBC_2.0 (dlopenold.c:77)
 ==12893==    by 0x4032BB3: ???
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==12893==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
 ==12893==    indirectly lost: 36 bytes in 1 blocks
 ==12893==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==12893==    still reachable: 823 bytes in 5 blocks
 ==12893==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==12893== 
 ==12893== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==12893== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 35 from 11)
```

I don't understand this output i don't see any file named dl-error,etc... in the folder.
Pleas tell me a right way to patch the problem.

**EDIT:**
As suggested I should use `gcc` with `-g` option to include debugging info ....but the problem is i am using make command and actually this implementation is not done by me.Its a standard packet generator tool and have some bug with it.I can't wait for the bug to be fixed so trying my own hand on it to fix it as my project has stucked in between due to this.So please tell me what should I do then .Is there a similiar switch for `make` or I have to change somewhere .As I am facing this situation first time so don't have any idea regarding how make and makefile works ?? If required I can add the contents of some files here.

**sendip.c (line no. 575)**

```
  575:       if(!mod->do_opt(opts[longindex].name,gnuoptarg,mod->pack)) {
  576:       printf("go to hell");// added by me but not printed.
  577:       usage=TRUE; 
  578:       }
```

**output of make command**

```
  udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2 $ make
  for subdir in mec ; do \
    cd $subdir ;\
    make  ;\
    cd ..  ;\
    done
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/udit/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec'
  make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/udit/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec'
  gcc -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-   
  prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align - 
  DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\"   -c -o sendip.o sendip.c
  sh -c "if [ `uname` = Linux ] ; then \
  gcc -o sendip -g  -rdynamic -ldl -lm -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall 
  -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs
  -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\" 
  sendip.o gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o ; \
  elif [ `uname` = SunOS ] ; then \
  gcc -o sendip -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm -ldl -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall
  -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs
  -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\"
  sendip.o gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o ;\
  else \
  gcc -o sendip -g -rdynamic -lm -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall 
  -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs
  -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\"
  sendip.o gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o ; \
  fi"
  ./help2man -n "Send arbitrary IP packets" -N >sendip.1
```

**Contents of Makefile : **

```
   #configureable stuff
   PREFIX ?= /usr/local
   BINDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/bin
   MANDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/share/man/man1
   LIBDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/lib/sendip
   #For most systems, this works
   INSTALL ?= install
   #For Solaris, you may need
   #INSTALL=/usr/ucb/install

   CFLAGS= -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith
   -Wwrite-strings \
   -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align \
                    -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"$(LIBDIR)\"
   #-Wcast-align causes problems on solaris, but not serious ones
   LDFLAGS=        -g -rdynamic -lm
   #LDFLAGS_SOLARIS= -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm
   LDFLAGS_SOLARIS= -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm -ldl
   LDFLAGS_LINUX= -g  -rdynamic -ldl -lm
   LIBCFLAGS= -shared
   CC=     gcc

   PROGS= sendip
   BASEPROTOS= ipv4.so ipv6.so
   IPPROTOS= icmp.so tcp.so udp.so
   UDPPROTOS= rip.so ripng.so ntp.so
   TCPPROTOS= bgp.so
   PROTOS= $(BASEPROTOS) $(IPPROTOS) $(UDPPROTOS) $(TCPPROTOS)
   LIBS= libsendipaux.a
   LIBOBJS= csum.o compact.o protoname.o headers.o parseargs.o cryptomod.o crc32.o
   SUBDIRS= mec

   all:    $(LIBS) subdirs sendip $(PROTOS) sendip.1 sendip.spec

   #there has to be a nice way to do this
   sendip: sendip.o        gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o
    sh -c "if [ `uname` = Linux ] ; then \
   $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS_LINUX) $(CFLAGS) $+ ; \
   elif [ `uname` = SunOS ] ; then \
   $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS_SOLARIS) $(CFLAGS) $+ ;\
   else \
   $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $+ ; \    
   fi"

   libsendipaux.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    ar vr $@ $?

   subdirs:
    for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
            cd $$subdir ;\
            make  ;\
            cd ..  ;\
            done

   protoname.o:    mec/protoname.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

   headers.o:      mec/headers.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

   parseargs.o:    mec/parseargs.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

   cryptomod.o:    mec/cryptomod.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

   crc32.o: mec/crc32table.h mec/crc32.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) mec/crc32.c

   mec/crc32table.h: mec/gen_crc32table
    mec/gen_crc32table > mec/crc32table.h

   sendip.1:       ./help2man $(PROGS) $(PROTOS) subdirs VERSION
                    ./help2man -n "Send arbitrary IP packets" -N >sendip.1

   sendip.spec:    sendip.spec.in VERSION
                    echo -n '%define ver ' >sendip.spec
                    cat VERSION >>sendip.spec
                    cat sendip.spec.in >>sendip.spec

    %.so: %.c $(LIBS)
                    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBCFLAGS) $+ $(LIBS)

   .PHONY: clean install

   clean:
                    rm -f *.o *~ *.so $(PROTOS) $(PROGS) $(LIBS) core gmon.out
                    for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
                            cd $$subdir ;\
                            make clean ;\
                            cd ..  ;\
                            done

   veryclean:
                    make clean
                    rm -f sendip.spec sendip.1

   install:                all
                    [ -d $(LIBDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)
                    [ -d $(BINDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
                    [ -d $(MANDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(MANDIR)
                    $(INSTALL) -m 755 $(PROGS) $(BINDIR)
                    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sendip.1 $(MANDIR)
                    $(INSTALL) -m 755 $(PROTOS) $(LIBDIR)
                    for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
                            cd $$subdir ;\
                            make install ;\
                            cd ..  ;\
                            done


     The problem is coming only with the module xorauth.so ,
     its not performing its work.So tell me how to include some 
     more debugging info ..
```

Comment: The dl functions are from the dynamic linker, which loads the shared libraries into your program.  Since that memory is still reachable it is not a leak and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
==12885==    by 0x804A51D: main (sendip.c:575)
```

indicates that the leaked memory was allocated at line 575 of `sendip.c` (by a function called on that line, which subsequently called down to `malloc()`).  You can't see the name of that function because whichever file it was in was not compiled with debugging info.

---

So the offending line is:

```
if(!mod->do_opt(opts[longindex].name,gnuoptarg,mod->pack)) {
```

This indicates that the memory leak is within the function `mod->do_opt()`.  `do_opt` is a function pointer within the structure `mod`, so you will need to find the point where this value is set to go deeper.

Answer (score 3):

There are can be several reasons of bad stack traces given by Memcheck tool. All of them are listed in Valgrind FAQ - [4.2. The stack traces given by Memcheck (or another tool) aren't helpful. How can I improve them?](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful). In this case you are using `dlopen` and `dlclose` while working with shared libs and therefore most likely debug info was discarded after `dlclose` and Valgrind failed to produce good stack trace. Workaround is to avoid calling `dlclose`.

> Also, for leak reports involving shared objects, if the shared object
>   is unloaded before the program terminates, Valgrind will discard the
>   debug information and the error message will be full of ??? entries.
>   The workaround here is to avoid calling dlclose on these shared
>   objects.

Comment: Another option is `--keep-debuginfo=yes`, then Valgrind will keep the debug information in order to show the stack traces, at the price of increased memory

Answer (score 2):

You should build your program and libraries with debug information (the `-g` option for gcc).  If you don't, valgrind can still find the leaks but cannot point out where in your source code the errors come from.  The `???` in the backtraces suggest that debug information is not available -- many of those should show function names and line numbers when debug info is present.

Comment: actually i did not used `gcc` command directly i am using `make` what else should i try with `make` so that it includes debugging info.

Comment: You could try adding it to the `CFLAGS` environment variable, eg. `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -g" make` instead of just `make`

Comment: @UditGupta By the looks of the makefile, it should be built with debug info already (the `-g` option is already used).  I'd recommend looking at caf's answer at this point.