# Weird valgrind errors

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

When memory debugging my program using `Valgrind` for the usual reasons I am greeted by the following errors (there are a lot of them):

```
==9895== Invalid read of size 4
==9895==    at 0x10D6C1: Shell (vshell.c:903)
==9895==    by 0x113608: exec_wrap (vib.c:111)
==9895==    by 0x111E8A: sm_thread (vproc.c:123)
==9895==    by 0x1107EC: tstart (vsched.c:130)
==9895==    by 0x55B3A8F: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so)
==9895==  Address 0x5973e90 is 134,800 bytes inside a block of size 135,168 alloc'd
==9895==    at 0x4C300B6: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==9895==    by 0x1106D0: alloc_thread (vsched.c:95)
==9895==    by 0x110825: sthread (vsched.c:144)
==9895==    by 0x112030: Exec (mproc.c:183)
==9895==    by 0x1137D9: Execute (vlib.c:166)
==9895==    by 0x10D9A5: bshell (shell.c:965)
==9895==    by 0x111E8A: smain_thread (mproc.c:123)
==9895==    by 0x1107EC: tstart (vsched.c:130)
==9895==    by 0x55B3A8F: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so)
```

Probing the usual places (e.g. here, `Valgrind`'s manual and Google) didn't yield any insight as to why this might happen. As far as I understand from the error messages the allocated block is *larger* than the one the address refers to, so I don't understand the "complain". As I initially said, there are many messages exactly like this one but in different parts of the code -- this is just an indicative error. Notably, when the program exits there are no actual leaks, as per `Valgrind` -- just these errors. Can anyone provide any insight as to why this happens?

Comment: "Invalid read of size 4" means that you try to read a 32-bit value you have not allocated memory for. On a 32-bit system it might be a pointer, otherwise it could be that you dereference an uninitialized pointer to read an `int`. Or something similar. Comb through your code to look for uninitialized local variables. Also, build with lots of warnings enabled, and fix all warnings you get.

Comment: It looks like you're reading from memory you never wrote to, and you're reading a 4-byte value from an odd memory address.

Comment: What is at that source line? Can you try using the gdb server?

Answer (score 0):

`Address 0x5973e90 is 134,800 bytes inside a block of size 135,168 alloc'd`
Obviously you are allocating less memory than needed on address `0x5973e90`
There's almost no way of helping with your program when you haven't provided any code at all. Check your allocation if the size matches the desired.

Comment: I think you are incorrect on this; from `Valgrind`'s documentation and answers related from SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662008/valgrind-giving-error-but-everything-seems-fine) or in Valgrind's forums [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/23179379/) both say the allocated block is of size indicated by the right value, in my case 135,168 while the other block size is indicated by the left value, which here is 134,800 -- so it is *less*. Additionally, the read error given is not *before* or *after* which would cause under or over flow. Anyhow, thanks.